# How to select count of the record including other fields in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have following LINQ query. I want to be able to **select** Count of the record selected as well. For example, select w.EndDate, **countOfRecordsSelected**.
How do I go about it ?

```
var ConferenceOrderedByDate = (from c in participant.Conference
                                          where c.Status == Status.Completed
                                          && c.EndDate.HasValue
                                          && c.EndDate <=Deadline
                                          && c.EndDate > MinimumDate
                                          orderby c.EndDate ascending
                                          select c.EndDate);
```

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: You mean a count of the _total_ records or a count for each `EndDate`?

Answer (score 1):

```
var ConferenceOrderedByDate = (from c in participant.Conference
                                      where c.Status == Status.Completed
                                      && c.EndDate.HasValue
                                      && c.EndDate <=Deadline
                                      && c.EndDate > MinimumDate
                                      orderby c.EndDate ascending
                                      select new { 
                                                   EndDate = c.Detail.EndDate,
                                                   Count = c.countOfRecordsSelected
                                                 });
```

this will create an anonymous type and you can access them by simply using ConferenceOrderedByDate.EndDate and ConferenceOrderedByDate.Count.

If you want the amount of records selected by the query, because I'm not sure which count you're referring to, just use

```
ConferenceOrderedByDate.Count()
```

Comment: Thanks ! But, countOfRecordsSelected is not a field of Conference. I need to be able to calculate it. How to do it ?

Comment: I thought that might be what you were asking for.  Already modified the end.

Comment: Yes, I want the amount of records selected by the query and want to be alble to include in as a field of anonymous type. Is it possible ? thx!